Mode propagation constant in optical fibers
$$\beta = k \sqrt{n_1^2 - \left(\frac{m\lambda}{2a}\right)^2}$$
where $m$ is one of the possible modes (from $0$ to $M-1$ where $M$ is no. of guided modes) and $a$ is the diameter of the optical fiber.
Is this formula for the mode propagation constant in optical fibers just some approximation? I can't find its derivation in any lecture note or the book that I referred to. All I found was the inequality $ n_2k_0 < \beta < n_1k_0$.

As a side note: this formula applies to step index fibers. Practical glass multimode fibers used in industry have parabolic index profiles. If the profile is perfectly parabolic then all modes will have the same propagation constant.
Of course if you are using a step-index fiber intended for single-mode operation with too short an optical wavelength so that it becomes multi-mode, then this is a useful formula to tell you how big a problem that might be.

Introduction to the Answer About "Mode propagation constant in optical fibers" 
See the reference:  Mode Theory of Circular Wave Guides quoted below:



Basically for a circular wave-guide with a core of index of refraction $n_{inner}$ and cladding of index of refraction $n_{outer}$, the beam is confined so longer as the effective index of refraction $n_{effective}$ is $n_{inner}<n_{effective}<n_{outer}$.
The indices of refraction is given by Wikipedia Snell's Law as:



When the light is highly confined inside the core, little of the optical power travels inside the cladding.  It is similar to a mirror in an optical tube where most of the light travels directly in the center at nearly maximum velocity $v_1=\frac{c_1}{n_1}$.  However, for larger wavelengths $\frac{\omega}{\beta}=c$, the light is not able to be confined in the faster-traveling inner region, and more and more of its power goes into the cladding (as long as $n_{effective}<n_2$ or outside of the cladding even when $n_{effective}>n_2$) resulting in optical power loss.
Maxwell's laws using the cylindrical coordinate Laplacian is how the modes and effective indices are calculated in this case.  I recommend Cheng's Field and Wave Electodynamics or Similar Graduate Electrodynamics book for more details on the exact calculation.
Derivation of the Formula for a Cylindrical Core and Cladding Fiber
Inside the Cylindrical Core, the light propagates according to:
$$(\nabla^2-\mu\epsilon\frac{\partial}{\partial t^2})\vec A=\vec 0$$
where the magnetic field is $\vec B=\vec \nabla \times \vec A$, and the magnetic vector potential is $\vec A$. The vector $\vec B$ points perpendicularly to the directions of propagation of the $\vec B$ field wave.
So to start to solve for the number of modes, one can look at the solution around $r=0$ in cylindrical coordinates for the $n_1$ region of the cylindrical waveguide pictured (and quoted from this link) below:



The mode of the wave propagation for the ground state is symmetric around the axis of propagation.  So this results in the field strength from the inside $n_1$ region being according to a $J_0$ cylindrical Bessel Function as quoted in the picture below.  This Bessel picture gives the value of the B-field versus radius in the inner core.  Then at the cladding, boundary conditions $\vec \nabla \times \vec B \frac1{u} = \vec{0}$ are applied to determine the fields in the core and cladding.
It is worthwhile to notice that the index of refraction $n_1>n_2$, that is that the index of refraction of the core is always greater than the index of refraction of the cladding for confinement.

It is worthy to remember the definition of the index of refraction as (quoted):

Index of Refraction: The ratio that describes how fast light travels
through a medium is known as the index of refraction n and is given as
n = c/v, where c is the speed of light in vacuum and v is the speed of
light in the medium in question.

That is since the index of refraction of the core is always greater than the index of refraction of the cladding, as the wave-mode becomes more concentrated in the core then $v_{mode}=\frac{c}{n_1}$ is slower.  As the wave becomes more concentrated in the cladding $v_{mode}=\frac{c}{n_2}$ is faster.  Applying boundary conditions in cylindrical coordinates depend on the index of refraction of the core and cladding and the width of the core.  Since there is always some light outside of the cladding, there is also loss associated with the light that is not confined, but usually the fiber is designed so that loss of optical power is very small as the wave propogates.
Derivation of Propagation in Cartesian Coordinates Using a Mirror Waveguide
Although I need more time to complete this section, the concept is that understanding propagation for two plane mirrors in cartesian coordinates is a lot easer to start with and makes it easier to come to relevant conclusions, which generally hold also for the more advanced coordinate systems such as cylindrical coordinates, without getting over-burdened with advanced calculation.  This step is very important because in some ways light confinement resembles mass propagation.  Consider the below diagram with two mirrors top and bottom and the wave propagates uniformly along the z-axis.  For mirrors, the electric field inside the metal is zero is the boundary condition:

Then Maxwell's equations can be applied to find the phase-velocity given a wavelength of a given value.  As shown in the diagram, the zero of the y-axis corresponds to the top of the bottom-mirror-plate.  Further, $y=L$ at the bottom of the top-mirror-plate. Applying Maxwell's Equations in the region between the mirrors (see the relevant Appendix) $\vec \nabla \times
\vec E = -\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \vec B $ and
$\vec\nabla \times \vec B \frac1{\mu}=\vec J + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \epsilon_0 \vec E \right)$ and
$\vec \nabla \times \vec \nabla \times
\vec E = -\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \vec \nabla \times\vec B
=-\mu_0 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\vec J - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \left( \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \vec E \right)$. Now, between the mirrors, the vacuum (with constants
$\mu=\mu_0$ and $\epsilon=\epsilon_0$) does not conduct current, so $\vec J=\vec 0$ there. So, $\vec \nabla \times \vec \nabla \times
\vec E = -\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \vec \nabla \times\vec B
= - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \left( \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \vec E \right)=\vec \nabla \vec \nabla \bullet \vec E -\nabla^2\vec E$.
Since this is a Cartesian coordinate system, a TE mode is selected so that the Electric Field in the $\hat x$ axis (not shown in the diagram, but perpendicular to $\hat y$ and $\hat z$ axis as usually drawn).  Thus $\vec E = E_0 \sin\left(k_y * y\right) e^{j*k_z*z - j*\omega*t} \hat x$, where $E_0$ is an arbitrary scaling factor for the Electric Field and $j=\sqrt{-1}$ as is usual for electrical engineering and also taking into account that the positive $k_z$ indicates a positive direction in $\hat z$ of momentum travel.
Just like with fiber-transmission of optical power, these mirrors also can support one or more modes.  The fundamental mode of this system has the relationship $k_y*L=\pi$ since at both mirror surfaces the Electrical Field must approach $\vec E=\vec 0$.  That is because inside the metal of the mirror, there is zero Electric field, and because the metal is modeled as a perfect conductor that enforces this zero Electric Field at each boundary condition.
Further, in Cartesian Coordinates, $\vec \nabla= \hat y \frac{\partial}{\partial y}+ \hat z \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ since the field is uniform in the perpendicular direction $\hat x$ that has no restrictive boundary.  Since the electric field is in the $\hat x$ axis direction, but the propagation $\vec \nabla= \hat y \frac{\partial}{\partial y}+ \hat z \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ is perpendicular, the term $\vec\nabla \bullet \vec E = \vec 0$. Then,
$\vec \nabla \times \vec \nabla \times
\vec E = -\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \vec \nabla \times\vec B
= - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \left( \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \vec E \right)=\vec \nabla \vec \nabla \bullet \vec E -\nabla^2\vec E
=-\nabla^2\vec E$ and $\nabla^2\vec E - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \left( \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \vec E \right)=\vec 0$ and
$\nabla^2 E_x \hat x - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \left( \mu_0 \epsilon_0 E_x \hat x \right)=0 \hat x$
in the vacuum region.  And with the speed of light $c$ given in vacuum as $c^2=\frac1{\mu_0\epsilon_0}$ then $\left(\nabla^2  - \frac1{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)E_x =0$.
Now, come back to $E_x = E_{0 x} \sin\left(k_y * y\right) e^{j*k_z*z - j*\omega*t}$ and insert this into the propagation Equation for $E_x$ to obtain $-\left(k_y\right)^2-\left(k_z\right)^2+\left(\frac{\omega}{c}\right)^2=0$ and therefore
$\left(\frac{\omega}{c}\right)^2=\left(k_y\right)^2+\left(k_z\right)^2$
Now, substituting the well-known relationship $\frac{\omega}{\beta}=c$, then the dispersion relationship is arrived as:
$$\beta^2=\left(k_y\right)^2+\left(k_z\right)^2 \text{ and } 
\omega^2=c^2 \left(\left(k_y\right)^2+\left(k_z\right)^2 \right)$$
Since the minimum value of $\left(\left(k_y\right)^2+\left(k_z\right)^2 \right)$ is
$\left(\left(k_y\right)^2 \right)$ where the photon has no forward motion in the $z$ direction and in some sense is "at rest", this equation shows the lower bound of what waves can be propagated in this mirror wave-guide.
From the equation
$$\vec E = \left(E_0 \sin\left(k_y * y\right) e^{\displaystyle j*k_z*z - j*\omega*t}\right) \hat x$$
the speed of the vector traveling in the $\hat z$ direction can be calculated as (since the light is traveling in a vacuum at the velocity of $c$ but its direction is not entirely in the $\hat z$ direction) as:
$$v_z=\frac{k_z}{\sqrt{k_y^2+k_z^2}}*c=\frac{k_z}{\beta}*c$$
Now consider the quote from the question:

$$\beta = k \sqrt{n_1^2 - \left(\frac{m\lambda}{2a}\right)^2}$$
where $m$ is one of the possible modes (from $0$ to $M-1$ where $M$ > is no. of guided modes) and $a$ is the diameter of the optical > > > fiber.

When the inside medium has an index of refraction of $n_1$, it reduces the maximum speed of light travel in that media from $\text{Speed }=c$ to $\text{Speed }=\frac{c}{n_1}$.  Also, still $\frac{\omega}{\beta}=\frac{c}{n_1}\underset{implies}\implies
\beta=n_1\frac{\omega}{c}$ is multiplied also by the factor $n_1$.
Implied from the quote:
$$\beta = k \sqrt{n_1^2 - \left(\frac{m\lambda}{2a}\right)^2} \underset{implies}\implies 
\beta^2=k^2\left(n_1^2 - \left(\frac{m\lambda}{2a}\right)^2 \right)
\\ \underset{implies}\implies  
k^2\left(n_1^2\right)=\beta^2+k^2*\left(\frac{m\lambda}{2a}\right)^2
$$
Now it is possible to understand the referenced Equation in the question to arrive at a result.  The term $k^2\left(n_1^2\right)$ accounts for unrestricted propagation in a medium of index of refraction $n_1$.
The second term $k^2*\left(\frac{m\lambda}{2a}\right)^2$ accounts for the confinement of the optical fiber radially.  The term $\beta^2$ accounts for the light as it travels down the fiber.
When $\beta=0$, as the propagation speed down the fiber approaches zero, there is now additional insight at this limit:
$$
k^2\left(n_1^2\right)=+k^2*\left(\frac{m\lambda}{2a}\right)^2
\underset{implies}\implies
m \frac{\lambda/2}{n_1}=a$$
But this is the boundary condition of the field being zero at mirrors of a cartesian waveguide.  And it is not the boundary condition of the field across two different indices as is the case with optical fiber, and also certainly-not in cylindrical coordinates.
So, back to the question:

Is this formula for the mode propagation constant in optical fibers
just some approximation?

Yes.  The formula is very much an approximation for the mode propagation constant in optical fibers, because the cladding index $n_2$ is not referenced at all in its calculation and also the Cylindrical Bessel Functions are not at all applied.
Appendix:  Maxwell's Equations in Differential Form
Maxwell's Equations in Differential form from Georgia State University are (quoted as follows)[http://hyperphysics.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/maxeq.html#c1]$^{[6]}$:



Appendix:  Helmholtz Equations in Cartesian, Cylindrical, and Spherical Coordinates
Maxwell's Equations can also be solved as in spherical coordinates:



The Equivalence of Mass and Photon Confinement in a Waveguide
While solving the Equations for a photon confined within a waveguide described by two parallel mirrors, the calculations can be expanded to describe mass-confinement because of the equivalence between energy-confinement and its associated mass:

$$\left(\nabla^2  - \frac1{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)E_x =0\text{  ,  }\vec E = \left(E_0 \sin\left(k_y * y\right) e^{\displaystyle j*k_z*z - j*\omega*t}\right) \hat x$$
Now, come back to $E_x = E_{0 x} \sin\left(k_y * y\right) e^{j*k_z*z - j*\omega*t}$ and insert this into the propagation Equation for $E_x$ to obtain $-\left(k_y\right)^2-\left(k_z\right)^2+\left(\frac{\omega}{c}\right)^2=0$ and therefore
$\left(\frac{\omega}{c}\right)^2=\left(k_y\right)^2+\left(k_z\right)^2$
Now, substituting the well-known relationship $\frac{\omega}{\beta}=c$, then the dispersion relationship is arrived as:
$$\beta^2=\left(k_y\right)^2+\left(k_z\right)^2 \text{ and } 
\omega^2=c^2 \left(\left(k_y\right)^2+\left(k_z\right)^2 \right)$$
Since the minimum value of $\left(\left(k_y\right)^2+\left(k_z\right)^2 \right)$ is
$\left(\left(k_y\right)^2 \right)$ where the photon has no forward motion in the $z$ direction and in some sense is "at rest", this equation shows the lower bound of what waves can be propagated in this mirror wave-guide.
The "at-rest" state is very similar to energy confined within mass, since the wave's photon-energy has been trapped between the two mirrors when $\beta=k_y$.
Propagation-Mass Equivalence
The very-famous formula $E=m*c^2$ describes mass-energy Equivalence.
Moreover, if $m_0$ is the rest-mass, then $E=m c^2= \frac{m_0 c^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$
Then,
$$m*c^2*\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}=m_0 c^2 
\implies m^2*c^2\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)=m_0^2*c^2$$
$$m^2\left(c^2-v^2\right)=m_0^2*c^2$$
$$m^2c^2\left(1-\frac{(k_z)^2}{\beta^2}\right)=(m_0)^2*c^2
=m^2c^2\left(\frac{k_0}{\beta}\right)^2$$
So,
$$\frac{(k_0)^2+(k_z)^2}{\beta^2}=\frac{\beta^2}{\beta^2}=1$$
And,
$$E=m*c^2\text{  ,  }E_0=\text{  Rest Mass }=\frac{k_0}{\beta}*m*c^2 $$
And
$$E_z=\sqrt{E^2-(E_0)^2}=\sqrt{m^2*c^4-\left(\frac{k_0}{\beta}\right)^2*m^2*c^4}=\frac{k_z}{\beta}*m*c^2=\frac{k_z}{\beta}{E}$$
$$E_z=\frac{k_z}{\beta}E=\frac{k_z}{\beta}\hbar \omega=m_z c^2$$
$$\implies m=\frac{\hbar \omega}{c^2}=\frac{\hbar \beta}{c}=\frac{h}{c*\lambda}$$
$$m_0=\text{  Rest Mass  }=\frac{h}{c*\lambda_\text{Wavelength at Rest}}$$
Inline References
$^{[6]}$: http://hyperphysics.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/maxeq.html#c1
